# FlatList render item absolute position

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, absolute, flatlist, react-native-gifted-chat

I have a list of chat messages (using React Native Gifted Chat, similar to using a FlatList), and I'm using an absolute view (let's call it view1) for each renderItem within it. I need view1 to be displayed above all other items. Currently, it appears as absolute to the current renderItem, but it's positioned behind the rest of the items in the list.

```
const RenderBubble = ({props}) => {
const showAvatar = Object.keys(props.nextMessage).length === 0;
return (
  <View>
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        setSelectedMessage(props.currentMessage._id);
      }}
      style={{backgroundColor: '#B9CCE5',
      borderColor: 'green',
      borderBottomRightRadius: 30,
      borderTopRightRadius: 30,
      borderTopLeftRadius: showAvatar ? 5 : 15,
      borderBottomLeftRadius: showAvatar ? 5 : 0,
      position:'relative',
      zIndex:-1,
      padding: 10}}>
      <Text>{props.currentMessage.text}</Text>
      {/* <Text>
        {props.currentMessage.reaction}
      </Text> */}


      {selectedMessage != null &&
        selectedMessage == props.currentMessage._id && (
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              position: 'absolute',
              top: -10,
              left: 8,
              zIndex: 40,
              backgroundColor: 'white',
              padding: 5,
            }}>
            {ReactionItems.map(Item => {
              return (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  key={Math.random().toString()}
                  onPress={() => {
                    updateMessages(props.currentMessage._id, Item.emoji);
                    setSelectedMessage(null);
                  }}>
                  <Text style={{marginHorizontal: 2}}>{Item.emoji}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              );
            })}
          </View>
        )}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);
```

};

Screen shot is given below

[image: I need to show the reaction view above all messages , but it is only showing absolute to current message in the list]